# how to pass a parameter to ChangeNotifierProvider in Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

so I have silly example like this

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isFemale;
  UserProvider(this.isFemale);
}


// I am confused when creating this userProvider below
final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose.family<bool><UserProvider((ref, isFemale) {
  return UserProvider(isFemale);
});



class MyPage extends ConsumerWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(context, watch) {

    final provider = watch(userProvider(false)); // <--- need to pass a bool from here

    return Container();
  }
}
```

I need to pass a boolean from `MyPage` widget to my `UserProvider` . but I am confused how to construct it because I have error like this

[image]

I am using: flutter_riverpod: ^0.14.0+3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your type arguments match the parameters.

First, you specify the class being provided, then the type you are passing through `family`.

```dart
final userProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose.family<UserProvider, bool>((ref, isFemale) {
  return UserProvider(isFemale);
});
```